# Can't configure Jetty and log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jetty, apache-commons-logging

Recently I inherited a project and having some hard time configuring the logging in the sense I can't seem to configure it at all!

So let me first give you the context:

1. It runs under Jetty 9.2
2. It uses the Apache Commons logging library
3. It has a Maven dependency on log4j which I assume the apache commons will pick that up and use it.
4. There are no existing commons-logging.properties or log4j.properties so I assume it falls back to defaults.
5. There is no jetty-logging.properties either.

So here is my problem, it currently does not log the timestamp, the output is like this:

```
5027 [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - Mapped URL path [/css/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

and:

```
912562 [qtp760972690-15] DEBUG com.xxx.xx.Class  - Some Action Log Msg
```

No idea what those fields before the DEBUG are. I had previously worked with Tomcat, sl4j and pretty sure Apache Commons logging too.

So I thought I would config files both 'commons-logging.properties' and 'log4j.properties' in the WAR file WEB-INF/classes.

Now it recognises and picks up the 'commons-logging.properties' but the 'log4j.properities' seems to have no effect at all.

So am I missing a step here, have I forgotten something? Is this a Jetty issue because it uses sl4j and I'm not?

Here is is m commons-logging.properties:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

And here is my log4j.properties:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout

# stdout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Another note is that log lines from Jetty itself do have the nice date-stamp I want:

```
2014-09-06 19:36:19.356:INFO:/:main: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
```

But not my main application logging.

Comment: Follow the steps mentioned in http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-log4j.html. And then see where your log4j.properties fits. Either in WEB-INF/lib or WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: I thought that was only for logging generated purely by Jetty outside my own application logging? Which if you see the last bit of my post, Jetty's own event logging produces date-timestamp. Or are they still somehow linked?

Comment: Ok. So you want it only for your application.

Comment: Jetty uses slf4j by default.And there is this slf4j-log4j bridge that is available. Try putting your log4j jar; slf4j-api jar; and slf4j-log4j jar in your web-inf/lib also with the log4j properties file.

Comment: I noticed the same problem. 'qtp760972690-15' displayed on the console for the logs.Not sure if its a bug. However if you redirect to a file using log4j file appender; it works fine.

Comment: I will try that out, in fact I might see if just switching and migrating to sl4j is easier which is in the to-do list.